# MySql, python, Visual Studio Code : No result set to fetch from

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to fetch rows from a table but always receiving "none" although there are 3 rows in the table.
I read same question several times on this forum but none of the solutions worked for me, so far I tried to set autocommit, explicit commits, buffered cursor, unbuffered cursor, fetchall, fetchone.
Select statement works fine in MySl workbench and returns 3 rows in MySql workbench,

This is my setup:

Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

MySql 8.0.11 Community Server - GPL Win64 (x86_64)

MySql Connector for Python 3.6.5

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect(database='test',
                           user='usr',
                           password='pwd',
                           host='localhost',
                           port=3306)

# autocommit -> advice from web
conn.autocommit = True
print(conn.autocommit)

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM testtable")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
# .... -> program stops here. please see output below 

res = len(rows)
print(res)
print(rows)

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Output:

> ```
> True
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "d:\PyDb\dbtest02_2.py", line 16, in <module>
>     rows = cursor.fetchall()
>   File "C:\Python\Python365\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py", line 488, in fetchall
>     raise errors.InterfaceError("No result set to fetch from.")
> mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: No result set to fetch from.
> ```

Many thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Strange: I just found out that it might has some thing to do with MS Visual Studio Code which I am using as editor. It seems to me that if I debug the script without breakpoints the fetch sometimes (?) works. If I am debugging step by step using some break points the fetch returns NONE.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

cur = conn.cursor()

showdata = "SELECT * FROM testtable"

try:

```
 cur.execute(showdata)
 rows = cur.fetchall()
 print(rows)
```

except:

```
 print ("Data not found!")
```

Answer (score 0):

For this specific case you do not need to set the connection to autocommit since you are only reading from a table.

- Check whether user has SELECT privileges on the table

Comment: Thanks for replies.

Comment: I found a workaround. I am using Visual Studio Code for editing and debugging. If there is a breakpoint between cursor.execute and cursor.fetchall somehow the result table is flushed. If there is no breakpoint between these two statments -> everything works as expected and the result table contains 3 rows.